# PHP form adds previous value in DB every time when I refresh page

Tags: php, sql, database, forms

I have created a form which has two input fields one is for input and second is for submission Although every thing is working until I refresh page suppose I have entered John as input and click submit it will add into DB but when I refresh page it will again add john in database and this happens in a cycle if I refresh page 100 times it will add john 100 times in DB I don't know why my if condition is not working `if(isset($_post['save'])`, my code is behaving like there is no if condition at all it is executing without checking if condition please assist me thanks in advance. Here is my code:

```
`<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/stylesheet.css">
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Secret message game</h1>
  <form id ="form-data" action="" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="user" id="user" autofocus placeholder="Enter your name" pattern="[a-z A-Z]{3,10}" title="a-z A-Z" required>
      <input type="submit" id="save" name="save">
  </form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
  if(isset($_POST['save'])){
    $value = $_POST['user'];

    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','website') or die("Connection failed");
    $query = "INSERT into user(name)
              values('{$value}')" or die(mysqli_error($con));

    $r = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die('Query failed!');

  }
?>
`
```

Comment: you should post it to a second page where you deal first with db then you redirect the page to page you like .also remember to close the mysql connection to avoid errors on db server. you choose right the use of mysqli witch is fastest than PDO ! be persistent in doing tests and you got the right answer by yourself

Comment: I did it but still issue is there

Comment: Can you share your edited code? The solution @Constantin suggested should work fine.

Comment: Did you mean I have to cut PHP code from this file and add it to new file I have done this if you meant it then I can share it with you

Comment: This is working as it's supposed to work, actually. You are redirecting the browser to the same page, but with a `post` request instead of the usual `get`. When you refresh or update the page afterwards, the browser will run the previous request again, which happens to be the `post`.

Comment: You have to put the php code in a other file, change the form action to that php file, and redirect back to the form file after you saved to the db.

Comment: Sir I just want to say million thanks to you